# How get return value of the RacSignal to

Tags: reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I have a beginner's question regarding the ReactiveCocoa.
I want to return the value of `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method based on user interaction with `UIAlertView`. 
That's what I have so far, obviously it doesn't work. How should I proceed?

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{
    if([identifier isEqualToString:ModalBrowser]){
        if(self.delegate.currentCoreConversation!=nil){
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Disconnect?" message:@"This action will disconnect you from your current conversation. Would you like to continue?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Heck No Techno!" otherButtonTitles:@"Certainly", nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView.rac_buttonClickedSignal subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *x) {
                //    return [x isEqual:@1];
            }];
            [alertView.rac_buttonClickedSignal subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *x) {
                //    return [x isEqual:@1];
            }];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert views don't block the thread of execution when displayed. In other words, the user's tap will arrive *after* you've already returned from `-shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

Instead of trying to figure out a way to change that behavior, you should return `NO` immediately, and then programmatically trigger a segue later (after the user has responded to your alert view).